# Added url to siteMapNode and it changed the title

Tags: asp.net, sitemap

I had a `siteMapNode` that looked like this:

```
<siteMapNode title="Home">
```

I added a url to a html page, so the `siteMapNode` looked like this:

```
<siteMapNode title="Home" url="..\..\homePage.html" >
```

The title was changed to "homePage".
Any ideas on why it happend and how I can fix it?

Comment: Check EnableLocalization property is true. Visit this link to refer more: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sitemapnode.title(v=vs.110).aspx